# Backbone.js : select option change event trigger click event also

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view for a selectbox with two events, change and click.

- change - additional functionality on selection.
- click  - to clear the current selection.

But when I do the change option, the click event is also getting triggered.

```
Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
    'change #sort-list': 'facetAction',
    'click #sort-list': 'clearSelection'
},
facetAction : function(){
},
clearSelection: function(){
 //change event this also getting executed.
}
```

Comment: instread of clear value on click you can put a cross button right side of dropdown and clear value on that button click. You can't prevent click event on change as first click event will be fire.

Comment: Thanks,But i want to show the close button inside the dropdown. In the above case first the change event is fired then the click event also.

Comment: You could reside your button outside of dropdown and position it via css

Comment: The point is that you can't stop the click event from happening because when the user selects an option using their mouse they do it by clicking so you will get a click event as well as a change event

Comment: are you sure first chnage event is fire then click event? i think its not possible and same for close button inside select tag you can't add inside select tag.

Comment: Yes ..change event fire first then the click event. Is there any way I can differentiate the two events?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `click #sort-list` more specific. If you use your mouse to change the selection of `#sort-list` it will also call `click`.

If you're trying to do a reset like you mention on `click`, create another button to the side of it or something like that. Then, handle `click #reset-button`.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="reset-button">Reset</button>
  </span>
  <select class="form-control" id="sort-list"></select>
</div><!-- /input-group -->

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'change #sort-list': this.onChangeSelectedItem,
        'click #reset-button': this.onClickResetButton
    }
});
```

Unless I am missing something, that's all that you need to do...